# CSS :active selector

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors

I can't seem to get the CSS :active selector to work. Below is my code, and here is what I've tried. I've added an "active" class to the the li a link, used the same class name for the ul group and added :active at the end, etc. Could some one please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <header role="navigation">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Isaac Luna</li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>



    html {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #264c95;
        background-size: 15px 15px;
        background-image: 
            linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.22) 1px, transparent 1px), 
            linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.22) 1px, transparent 1px);
    }

nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        background-image: url(texture.png);
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 46px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 46px;
    }

    li {
        height: 46px;
        float: left;
    }

    li:first-child {
        height: 18px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a {
        height: 18px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    .nav-item:hover {
        display: block;
        background-color: #264c95;
    }

    .nav-item:active {
        display: block;
        background-color: #264c95;
    }

    .nav-item .active:active {
        display: block;
        background-color: #264c95;
    }

    .nav-item #PageActive:active {
        display: block;
        background-color: #264c95;
    }
```

Comment: we cant debug img post code plz

Comment: Code should be posted within the question as text and not as screenshot.

Comment: select all ur code and press ctrl + k

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: add Class active  with  class nav-item which you want to highlight. then  write css .active{   }

Comment: No luck. Still remains un-active.

Comment: `:active` selector represents the state an element is in when a key or button (mouse or otherwise) is down. Once that key/button is up (released), the subject is no longer in an *active state*.

Comment: What do you think should be happening, and what is happening instead?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add active class to a

```
    .nav-item a:active {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

for .nav-item

```
.nav-item:active {
            background-color: brown;
        }
```

**update**

I think you are looking for hover effect try below code

```
.nav-item:hover, .nav-item:active {
    background-color: brown;
}
```

you can check that by inspect element in that particular element and by going to active state

hope it helps

Comment: I used the second one and nothing happened at first. But when I on the links. It flashes the active color for a second. It seems that something it overwriting it.

Comment: You can't use `:active` on non-interactive elements.

Comment: I have hover working. But I want the page that you are on to be active in the nav-bar. I used inspect and the css for :active did not appear. And when I would hover over the elements it worked as it should, but when I clicked to go to another page, the hover color would flash to the color I have set for active and disappear. TIP: I used red as the color for active to see it better.

Comment: you are talking about active class so u need to add it through js or manually

Comment: "But I want the page that you are on to be active in the nav-bar" — That isn't what `:active` means. `:active` means "Is currently being clicked on".